# vba wait till input captcha submit form

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA.
I am creating vba for login to website and get information, but when i tries to login it ask for captcha . I need a code to wait till captcha is inputed and form submitted. please help me on this.

```
Sub iepart2()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://adb.in/ser/"

        Do While .busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readystate <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set txtUname = .document.getelementbyid("txtUname")
        txtUname.Value = "Amarindaz"
        Set txtEmail = .document.getelementbyid("txtEmail")
        txtEmail.Value = "Amarindaz@gmail.com"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to use wait in code. Just split the code into 2 parts, and let the user do the captcha in between.

1. Code: Prefill the login form. (You have this already). Do nothing more.
2. User manually enters captcha.
3. Code: Gets the information it needs, from inside the website. (new code). Needs to be invoked/called after the succesful login (after captcha).

To do this, you just need to more persistently store the IE object (using Static, or Public keywords, instead of Dim). This will allow you to continiue using the same object (browser window) after the user typed in the captcha.

To give you some idea of what I mean, here is a pseudo code, utilizing Public Module level `ie` variable. Just copy into blank module:

```
Public ie As Object

Sub login()

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://adb.in/ser/"
    'all the other login stuff. filling in the input elements

End Sub

Sub query() 'Just for demonstration, nothing useful going on here :)
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Visible = True
End Sub
```